# Is it possible to use argparse for passing optional arguments without the dash symbol?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program which can take in a few different arguments, and depending on what the argument is that is passed, that function is called in the python program. I know how to use sys.arv, and I have used argparse before, however I am not sure how to go about accomplishing the following with argparse..

Possible arguments: func1, func2, func3

Program could be executed with either of the following:

```
python myprogram func1
python myprogram func2
python myprogram func3
```

Therefore the arg passed correlates to a function in the program. I do not want to include any dashes in the arguments so nothing like -func1 or -func2...etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 parser.add_argument('foo', choices=['func1','func2','func3'])
```

will accept one string, and raise an error if that string is not one of the chocies.  The results will be a namespace like

```
 Namespace(foo='func1')
```

and

```
 print(args.foo)
 # 'func1'
```

Is that what you want?

The subparsers mechanism does the same thing, but also lets you define added arguents that can differ depending on which subparser is given.

Comment: Yes, that was much simpler than I originally thought it would be. Thank you!

Comment: Just one question...How can I make a call to the function based on the arg that was passed? Something like args.foo() or foo() ?

Comment: You have to match the string with the function, for example with a dictionary.  `dd = {'func1':func1, 'func2':func2};  dd[args.foo]()`.  The `docs` describes a different mechanism when using subparsers (using `setdefault`).

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively if the functions are in a module called `module` then you could call it as `getattr(module, args.foo)()`. Normally you don't like to look up code in a module using user input, because they could type anything, but in this case you've explicitly constrained their choices already so it's not so bad. If the functions are in the current module you can get it as `sys.modules[__name__]`, or do `globals()[args.foo]`.

Comment: Thank you @SteveJessop . Do either of you know if it is possible to require an additional parameter for one of the functions in the list? Let's say func2 requires an additional parameter, it needs to be run like "python myprogram func2 param" I haven't really been able to find examples of argparsed being used this way

Comment: I mentioned `subparsers` as a way of requiring additional parameters.  Read the docs and try the examples.